# What Language shoud i use to write a script that generates scripts from text?

Tags: parsing, generator

I need to create a parser actually. I have the scripts pattern as text in a table, and each row of the column need to be parsed into code. The text contains the keywords for the functions and instructions that need to be used.
Which language is best suited for this ?

Comment: would flag this for primarily opinion based but i have no flags left for today

Comment: @WhatsThePoint, flagged ;)

Comment: was i too vague? What other details do you need? sorry, but i'm 1 hr old on this site. :D

Comment: *"Which language is best suited for this ?"*... which language are you most comfortable with?

Comment: ok, if i would have asked " Which language are you most comfortable with? And which language do you recommend me to use?" What would have been the answer?